# Quantstrat add.indicator x=quote(Hi(mktdata)) somehow not recognizing column

Tags: r, quantstrat

Curious issue in quantstrat.
I am attempting to add.indicator of a standard TTR function to the high of some data. 
the code snippet is as follows:

```
 add.indicator(strategy.st,name="runMax",
          arguments = list (x=quote(Cl(mktdata)),n=entry_period),
           label = "Max55")
```

That works BUT the following

```
add.indicator(strategy.st,name="runMax",
          arguments = list (x=quote(Hi(mktdata)),n=entry_period),
          label = "Max55")
```

Does not.
I have tried

(x=quote(Cl(mktdata))

(x=quote(Vo(mktdata))

(Op(mktdata))

which all work 
And

(x=quote(Hi(mktdata))

(x=quote(Lo(mktdata))

Which do not.
any ideas? 
The data is a standard call to google and saved as Rdata.

The error is as follows:

```
Error in (function (x, n = 10, cumulative = FALSE)  : 
ncol(x) > 1. runMax only supports univariate 'x'
```

Curious as it works with the Close data.

The full code:

```
require(quantstrat)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)

initDate = "1990-01-01"
from = "2007-01-01"
to = "2012-12-31"

options(width =70) # set the output width 

currency('USD')
Sys.setenv(TZ ="UTC")

require(quantmod)

symbols = c("MSFT")

load("~/R_backtrade_test/MSFT.Rdata")

stock(symbols,currency='USD',multiplier = 1)

tradeSize <- 100000
initEq <- tradeSize*length(symbols) 

strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "turtles"

rm.strat(strategy.st)

initPortf(portfolio.st,symbols = symbols,initDate = initDate,currency =       'USD')
initAcct(account.st,portfolios = portfolio.st,initDate =    initDate,currency = 'USD',initEq = initEq)
initOrders(portfolio.st,initDate = initDate)
strategy(strategy.st,store = TRUE)

strat <- getStrategy(strategy.st)

ATRperiod = 20
entry_period = 55
exit_period = 20

add.indicator(strategy.st,name="ATR",
          arguments = list(HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata)),n=ATRperiod),
          label = "ATR20")

add.indicator(strategy.st,name="runMax",
          arguments = list (x=quote(Hi(mktdata)),n=entry_period),label = "Max55")

test <- applyIndicators(strategy.st,mktdata= MSFT)
head(test,60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
add.indicator(strategy.st,name="runMax",
              arguments = list (x=quote(Hi(mktdata)[, 1]),n=entry_period),label = "Max55")
```

This assumes the first column with 'high' in its column name is the right one.  Or you can be more cautious, with this instead:

```
add.indicator(strategy.st,name="runMax",
              arguments = list (x=quote(Hi(mktdata)[, "MSFT.High"]),n=entry_period),label = "Max55")
```

The error you get hints at what the problem is.  You're unintentionally passing in more than one column in to the call for `runMax` when applyIndicators runs.

> runMax only supports univariate 'x'.

To see how this error comes about, try running your code without adding the `runMax` indicator.  Look at the mktdata:

```
> head(Hi(mktdata), 2)
           MSFT.High trueHigh.ATR20
2007-01-03    38.927             NA
2007-01-04    38.567         38.567
```

Your call to computing the ATR generates a column name with 'high' in it.

Those two columns will be passed to the call to `runMax` in `applyIndicators`, and thats how your error comes about.  I've seen many errors come about from using `Op`, `Hi`, `Lo`, `Cl` in quantstrat code that occur for the same kinds of reasons that caused your problem, and therefore *almost always* avoid using these helper functions in any code I write.  Specifically requesting the specific name of the "High" column avoids these problems people keep on experiencing with these helper functions.